# How JPA overcome the issues in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am currently working in Hibernate.

Now i am going to switch to Hibernate JPA. I want to know the reason why we prefer Hibernate JPA rather than Hibernate. 
**What are the issues of Hibernate overcome by the JPA.**

I face some issues in Hibernate like sub query generation while iterate persistence class. 
Are these kind of problem overcame by JPA ??

**And if possible please share some tutorial links for me to learn JPA.** 
**(Don't forget i am the beginner in Hibernate JPA).**

Thanks In Advance,

K.Ramkumar

Comment: Hibernate *is* one of JPA's implementations. And I don't get your problem, can you expand on that/post sample code?

Answer (score 0):

The JPA is part of the JEE specification which means any SOftware which
wants to be JEE conform must fullfill the JPA specification.

JPA itself is only a specifiaction and there exist many frameworks like Hibernate or
TopLink and so on which implement this specifiaction.

This means if you just use the JPA functionallity within you programm it
has more compatibility to different kind of JEE conform software. 
Which can be an advantage. The main disadvantage is that you lose some
specialized functionallity which is provided by the implementing framework 
but not regarded by the JPA spec.

So you can see JPA as a subset of interfaces in order to provide Object Relational Mapping functionallity.

Hope it was the answer to you question.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes Pls. correct me, but i think it is not part of JSE until now. Is part of JEE 6.